# Krull Topology on Galois Groups (two equivalent(?) definitions).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups

I'm starting to study Infinite Galois Theory and its relation with Profinite Groups, but I'm having troubles with basic definitions.

> **Definition 1.** Let $K/F$ a Galois extension. Write
>   $$\mathcal{F} = \{L \mid L \text{ is a subfield of }K\text{ s.t. } L/F\text{ is a finite Galois extension}\}.$$
>   We define a topology in $\mathrm{Gak}(K/F)$ by taking as a base of open neighborhoods of $1$ the family of subgroups
>   $$\mathcal{N} = \{\mathrm{Gal}(K/L) \mid L \in \mathcal{F}\}.$$
>
> **Definition 2.** The Krull Topology on $\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$ is defined as follows: A subset $X$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$ is open if is empty or $X = \bigcup_{i}g_{i}N_{i}$ for some $g_{i} \in G$ and $N_{i} \in \mathcal{N}$.

We can show that, according to definition 2, the basis of Krull Topology is
$$\{gN \mid g \in G, N \in \mathcal{N}\},$$
but I just can see that taking $g = 1$, the definition 2 becomes the definition 1.

**Questions:**

1. *How can I see that 1 and 2 defines the same topology?*

Maybe it's a stupid question, but

2. *Why defining the open neighborhoods of $1$ it's enough to generate a topology?*

I can see why the definition 2 works. Unfortunately, my book uses the definition 1. Thus, I would like to understand why that definition works and is equivalent to the second.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The thing is that we don't just define any topology, we define a group topology. This means that we want a topology that makes $G=Gal(K/F)$ a topological group. A topological group is homogeneous as a topological space, so as far as the topology goes, the points are all indistinguishable. This is because if $g\in G$ is any point, then the map $\lambda_g: G\to G$ given by $x\mapsto gx$ is a homeomorphism that sends $1$ to $g$.

So if you want to describe a basis of open neighborhoods of any point, you only need to describe it for $1$. It is then implied that if $\{U_i\}$ is a basis of neighborhoods for $1$, then $\{gU_i\}$ is taken as a basis of neighborhoods for $g$.

With this in mind, you can check that the two descriptions are the same.

Comment: I got it. Great explanation!